# Creating an Audit in SQL Server 2008 SP1

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm attempting to trace Inserts and Updates to a pair of tables in SQL Server 2008 (Service Pack 1, Developer Edition) and it's returning an error when I try to view the logs.

This is the script when I used the Wizard to create the Audit:

```
    USE [master]
    GO

    CREATE SERVER AUDIT [Audit-Tables]
    TO FILE 
    (   FILEPATH = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\'
        ,MAXSIZE = 20 MB
        ,MAX_ROLLOVER_FILES = 5
        ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF
    )
    WITH
    (   QUEUE_DELAY = 1000
        ,ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE
        ,AUDIT_GUID = '53cd958f-5b16-49d9-8cb2-4c7f26995f87'
    )
    ALTER SERVER AUDIT [Audit-Tables] WITH (STATE = ON)
    GO
```

When I attempt to view the logs, I get the error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

This is even before I've added any Database Audits.

I tried it out first on the Dev server (SQL Server 2012) and it worked fine. Is this a known issue with 2008?

Comment: When you "attempt to view the code" ***where***?

Comment: From Microsoft documentation - SQL Server 2012 (11.x) through SQL Server 2017. 2008 did not have this feature. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-server-audit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Sorry, meant "logs", not "code". And you have probably answered the question, I am using SSMS 2017, and it's giving me options that aren't applicable.
Also, though Auditing was a new feature of 2008, it was for Enterprise edition only. So I'll have to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1954/sql-server-2008-auditing-feature/) article, Auditing was available in 2008, but only for Enterprise Edition, not Developer. I just wish the error message had been more useful.